# Indentation of HTML in PHP files within PhpStorm

Tags: html, formatting, phpstorm

In a *.php* file I have a the following code

```
<? include 'header.php' ?>
    <form action="/">
        <input>
    </form>
<? include 'footer.php' ?>
```

How can I delete the 4 indents before the HTML tag when I press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+L</kbd>? It should look like this:

```
<? include 'header.php' ?>
<form action="/">
    <input>
</form>
<? include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: select the block of codes and press `shift+TAB` key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+L</kbd> is the shortcut for `Reformat Code`, which automatically applies the code indentation rules set in the PhpStorm settings.

It is currently **not possible** to make the code look like you want *automatically*. You would have to format the code manually every time.

The reason is the limitation of the PhpStorm formatting engine. There is already feature request at the PhpStorm issue tracker which addresses the issue: [WI-32401](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32401)
Also see this issue report: [WI-17786](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17786)

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug with PhpStorm. Until it is fixed, simply put a new line after your last closing `PHP` tag.

```
<? include 'header.php' ?>
<form action="/">
    <input>
</form>
<? include 'footer.php' ?>
// new line here
```

Comment: Still valid in 2020!

Comment: And also in 2023

Answer (score 0):

Select area before `form` tag with mouse middle button then delete how much area you want to remove. Holding mouse middle button will select columns (indents). Hope it will help you in some other situations too.